# Sublime Text 2 - making javascript build with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext2

I’m trying to make a Javascript build system in Sublime Text 2 using Node.js. The problem is I don’t know where Node.js is installed on my mac (I installed it with mac installer and am running Mountain Lion) or how to properly assign a path variable to find it.

Comment: Go to your folder with the node program, and run 'node app' or 'node server' (depending on your main file). If that doesn't work try 'nodejs app' or 'nodejs server' ?

Comment: Run `which node` in Terminal to find out where the binary is located...

Answer (score 5):

If you haven't already, [install Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/installation#st2) in Sublime, then install the [`Nodejs`](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Nodejs) plugin. This should get you a lot farther than trying to build everything from scratch.

Once Nodejs is installed, open `Preferences -> Package Settings -> Nodejs -> Settings - Default` **and** `Settings - User`. Copy the entire contents of `Default` to `User` so you can edit it, then close `Default`. (*If you edit* `Default`, *any changes will be overwritten on upgrade.*) Change `"node_command"` and `"npm_command"` from `false` to the full path returned by running `which node` and `which npm` from Terminal.app.

For example, if `which node` returns `/usr/local/bin/node`, and `which npm` returns `/usr/local/bin/npm`, then your settings file should look like this:

```json
{
    // save before running commands
    "save_first": true,
    // if present, use this command instead of plain "node"
    // e.g. "/usr/bin/node" or "C:\bin\node.exe"
    "node_command": "/usr/local/bin/node",
    // Same for NPM command
    "npm_command": "/usr/local/bin/npm",
    // as 'NODE_PATH' environment variable for node runtime
    "node_path": false,

    "expert_mode": false,

    "ouput_to_new_tab": false
}
```

Save the file, and you should now be able to successfully use the commands in `Tools -> Nodejs`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I installed package control, the Nodejs plugin and followed your instructions. When I use the run command under Tools->Node.js I see a path to my .js file appear in the status window for a few seconds and then it disappears. When I use the build command it returns “node: command not found”. Any idea what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: If you run `which node` from Terminal, what does it return?